# How to make English character detected in a text field?

Tags: javascript

```js
$(".textTest input").keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().match(/[^A-Za-z]/ig)) {
        alert('english detected');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textTest">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

I wanna make this input detect English system, so, if I put any alphabet then the script alert the message "english detected".

Comment: Does this not work?

Comment: @LoganDevine Hi Logan! yes it is not working :(

Comment: You need to load jQuery and the input you're testing must exist before you run your own script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please read this document, [regular_expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges)

```js
$(".textTest input").keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().match(/[A-Za-z]/ig)) {
        alert('english detected');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll also refer here to the [StackOverflow regex tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)

Answer (score 1):

First, for only testing regex (without extracting values from its group) in js, you should use [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Second, you place the `^` in the wrong place (it should be the very first character in the regex).

Third, you should also specify `$` at end to stick the regex to the end of the string.

Fourth, there is no point at using the `i` flag (which does case insensitive match) and specifying both upper and lower cases.

Here's the updated version:

```js
$(".textTest input").keyup(function () {
    if (/^[a-z]$/ig.test($(this).val())) {
        alert('english detected');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textTest">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: the `^` in `[^character-range-groups]` tells it to "don't match these".

Comment: @LoganDevine Of course, but that's not what the OP want: he want to detect _English_, not anything that _it's not_.

Comment: Just saying that for those who haven't used regex before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add jQuery to your project.

You can do this by adding this to your `<head>`:

```
<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is close to correct. Just remove `^`

```
$(".textTest input").keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().match(/[A-Za-z]/ig)) {
        alert('english detected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `^[a-zA-Z]+$`, for things like `abCdeFg`, doesn't include space.